# Pronunciation of "to" as [tʃu:]

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants, palatalization

After doing some research, I have noticed I have been saying the word "to" as [tʃu:], while most dictionaries and sources say I should pronounce it as [tu:]. But I have the impression that "to" is not pronounced with a clear t, at least in the most common variants of English. This also seems to happen with other words beginning with "to", such as "tomorrow" and "today".

Is this pronunciation of "to", [tʃu:], valid?

Are there any variations regarding the "t" in this word (excluding the "quick" informal pronunciations, which I am aware of)?

I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I don't know how all native speakers pronounce things, so I can't state definitively that none of them say [tʃu:], but I would certainly recommend  against using it if you are learning English.

Comment: Are you hearing this from Americans, Brits, or Australians?

Answer (score 4):

Your pronunciation `[tʃu:]` of the word *to* is **not** correct. In fact, that's how the word *chew* is pronounced.

What you hear when native speakers pronouce the word *to* is an [aspirated T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant). So *to* is pronounced `[tʰu:]` when stressed. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Pronunciation) for more details.

Comment: I understand. I was in doubt because it is really common for Brazilians (like me) to say "to" as "chew" when stressed, even for teachers! Probably it is our approximation for the aspirated t. Curiously, this only happens before an "o".

Comment: @RoggerAlves: yes, I have heard this pronunciation is used by some Brazilians. But I have never heard of a native speaker using it.

Comment: So this is part of what would be your "Brazilian accent" when you are in the US.

Comment: Note that aspirated /t/ is also somewhat affricated in most dialects of English, making it something more like [tˢʰuː]. That affrication is what makes speakers of some languages hear it as a [tʃ].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think it's true of most English, or even Irish  accents, although I think that there's an element of it in Welsh and Scottish speech. In most English ones including RP there is more of a tendency to shorten, or even drop, the 'o' rather than soften the 't' so you get "I'm going t'get my car serviced". The only word I can think of with a softened 't' is "Tuesday' which very often comes out as "Chewsday".

Comment: @BoldBen Scottish is actually one of the relatively few English accent groups where affrication is _not_ the rule. I don’t know what you mean by a ‘softened’ t (it could mean a number of different things), but if you’re referring to /tʃ/ (as in _church_), that’s not a ‘softened’ t, just a completely different phoneme. When I talk about an affricated, aspirated [tˢʰ], that’s a different sound, like the t in _take_. If you compare a Londoner and a Scot saying that word, you can hear that the Londoner’s t is more ‘s-like’, more towards how Germans pronounce z, as in _zehn_ ‘ten’.

Answer (score 3):

You'll hear [tʃu:]in inner-city Dublin - it would not be considered a good example of how to speak

Comment: Well, if you were in inner-city Dublin, it would be

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, while most dialects of English don't affricate the /t/ in "to", there are several that affricate the /t/ in "Tuesday". Why? Etymology: The "ue" was once pronounced /ju/; as time went on and English evolved, some dialects simply dropped the /j/, while others assimilated it with the /t/ into an affricate /tʃ/. Same thing happened to "due", which some dialects affricate (the same ones that affricate "Tuesday") while others don't.
And /j/ is not the only approximant that affricates /t/ and /d/. Almost all dialects affricate /t/ and /d/ before /ɹ/, and many do it before /w/, producing /tʃɹ/ and /tʃw/. Do note that while /tʃɹ/ and /dʒɹ/ are fairly standard, /tʃw/ and /dʒw/ are not - you're more likely to hear /twelve/ and /dwarf/ than /tʃwelve/ and /dʒwarf/.

Comment: [Shchtrongly related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2X1pKEHIYw). :)

Comment: To is almost always pronounced /tə/.

Comment: @Xanne When it's unstressed, which it admittedly usually is. But when it's stressed, "to" is /tu/, just like "too" and "two"

Answer (score 1):

Since (many varieties of) Brazilian Portuguese palatalizes /t/ and /d/ before high front vowels /i/, (*tia* 'aunt' [tʃia], *dia* 'day' [dʒia]) and /u/ is a high back vowel, it's not uncommon for Brazilian Portuguese speakers to pronounce English /tu/ as /tʃu/ but this doesn't match most English pronunciations of these words.

The English pattern is made more confusing since many English speakers do palatalize some /u/ sounds, although these are always orthographic 'u' or 'ew' and never orthographic 'o'.

So words like *to*, *two*, *do*, *toot*, *cartoon* are always pronounced [tʰu] or [du] if the syllable containing the /u/ is stressed. Since infinitival and *to* and prepositional *to* are usually unstressed, they are usually pronounced as [tʰǝ].

Words with orthographic 'u' like *tune*, *Tuesday*, *due* are pronounced in many varieties of English as either [tʲu] or [tʃu] or [dʲu] or  [dʒu].

Comment: There is also the fact that tomorrow and today versus to noun or infinitive are not the same.